# Force tag synonym if a mod tries to make one, even if it's already suggested

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, moderator-tools

So as a mod there are two different ways I can make a tag synonym; I can *suggest* it and it goes through voting like normal, or I can just make the dang thing myself immediately without voting.

I accidentally *suggested* a synonym instead of *making* one outright (because the UI for doing this is spread across like 5 pages). I then tried to just go to the mod tool to create the tag synonym directly, but for this error:

[image]

In the end I had to go to the [tag synonyms page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and click an approve button. No, I couldn't approve it from the [page I created the synonym on](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/color-scheme/synonyms) either. So that's three pages I went and acted on just to do one thing. Could you please just forgo the "Synonym was already proposed" error and just quietly turn that into an "approve this tag synonym"? They mean the exact same thing and have the same ends, the way it works is just awkward and frustrating.

Comment: "that's three pages I went and acted on just to do one thing" is stretching things a bit -- it took three pages because you messed up multiple times. It could've taken one page, or several thousand if you messed up badly enough

Comment: @MichaelMrozek It should really be possible from *any* of the pages since I have a binding vote. There are three possible pages to do the same thing, and only some of them work provided you've done/not done certain things on other pages in the set. It should *not* work that way

Comment: The page that allows a moderator to create a tag synonym is at /admin/merge-tags. In that page you enter the tag names; in the next page, you review the results of what you are doing, and tell Stack Exchange to proceed. It is not really spread over 5 pages.

Comment: Well, you still have to be notified of the other synonym proposal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In this case, the proposed synonym was created from the moderator because he didn't want to use the page that would allow him to directly create the synonym. If there is a synonym already suggested, moderators can approve it without voting it, from /tags/synonyms.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you're missing the point; if I'm trying to create that synonym it does the same thing as approving it. Just let me do it from this page too. There's no need to force me around to do the same thing on a different page like that. If I'm clearly trying to do X and X has the same effect as Y, X should just cause Y not tell me to go to another page to do it.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how many times does what you describe happen? Plus, I could have suggested a synonym tag because I want other users to vote it. If then I forget about that, and try creating it, I would like to be warned about that.